# How to traverse xml through jquery?

Tags: javascript, xml, jquery

I am trying to traverse a rss feed in which a tag is present like below

```
<item>
<itunes:explicit>​no​</itunes:explicit>​
</item>
```

how do i get the value of itunes:explicit. i tried like below

```
_this = loadedData // xml data from the ajax request
$(_this).find('item').find('itunes:explicit').text()
```

It is not returning the text present in it.

Any way to access this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the colon in your selector so that jQuery doesn't interpret the colon as a CSS pseudo-class:

```
$(_this).find('itunes\\:explicit').text()
```

Comment: yeah i missed that..+1 for this

Answer (score 2):

user parseXML, [described here.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

Comment: The OP has already got an XML document directly from the response to an Ajax request, so there's no need to parse the XML.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly find the thing which you want..you don't need heirarchy for that..try with this code-

```
$(_this).find('itunes\\:explicit').text()
```